# How to write test code for custom hook using recoil

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, recoiljs

I'm writing a test code with Jest for a custom hook in my web application.

It uses Recoil for state management, but the error message appears when I run `npm run test`.

This is the error message.

```
 This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component.

      16 | const useIds = () => {
      17 |   // const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);
    > 18 |   const [ids, setIds] = useRecoilState(idsState);
         |                         ^
```

This is the test code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useIds } from '@/hooks/useIds';
import { RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';

it('unit test for custom hook useIds', () => {
  const TestComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const ids = useIds();

    return (
      <RecoilRoot>
        <div title='ids'>{ ids }</div>
      </RecoilRoot>
  )
  }

  const { getByTitle } = render(<TestComponent />);
  const ids = getByTitle('ids');
})
```

This is the custom hook code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { atom, useRecoilState } from 'recoil';

import { fetchIdsByType } from '@/repositories';

const initialState: {
  [type: string]: number[];
} = {};

export const idsState = atom({
  key: 'idsState',
  default: initialState,
});

const useIds = () => {
  const [ids, setIds] = useRecoilState(idsState);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { type } = router.query;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (router.asPath !== router.route) {
      // @ts-ignore
      fetchIdsByType(type).then((ids: number[]) => {
        setIds((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            // @ts-ignore
            [type]: ids,
          };
        });
      });
    }
  }, [router]);

  // @ts-ignore
  return ids[type];
};

export { useIds };
```

I know why the error is happening but I have no idea where the `RecoilRoot` should be in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to put where to wrap the component which is using your custom hook as following:

```js
it('unit test for custom hook useIds', () => {
  const TestComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const ids = useIds();

    return (
      <div title='ids'>{ ids }</div>
    )
  }

  const { getByTitle } = render(
    // Put it here to wrap your custom hook
    <RecoilRoot>
      <TestComponent />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
  const ids = getByTitle('ids');
})
```